# Android adding dynamic button click disabled when adding edittext

Tags: android, button, dynamic

I am dynamically adding a button to a frame layout. Which works great. When I add an edittext object to the same frame layout, it appears the functionality of being able to click the button appears to stop.

Can anybody help me with this. Here is my code: -

```
    FrameLayout reportLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.reportDetailLayout);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button executeButton = new Button(this);

    executeButton.setClickable(true);

    executeButton.setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(executeButton));

    EditText text1 = new EditText(this);

    executeButton.setText("Execute");
    executeButton.setMinimumHeight(10);
    executeButton.setMinimumWidth(150);

    text1.setId(1);
    text1.setHint("Enter Value");

    executeButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text1.setPadding(12, 70, 0, 0);

    executeButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    text1.setLayoutParams(params);

    reportLayout.addView(executeButton);
    reportLayout.addView(text1);
```

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0):

your edit text is top of your button. your touch event can clicks only edit texts area.
you change button or edit text's location, i think this problem will solve.

Comment: How can I change the location of the edit text. Is that with the padding method.

Comment: for example move edittext `((FrameLayout.LayoutParams)text1.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = executeButton.getWidth()+10;`    (if getWidth() returns 0 you should change it like this ) `((FrameLayout.LayoutParams)text1.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = 160;`   (160 and +10 is my assumption you can change them what you want).

Answer (score 0):

It needed to be a Linear Layout.